# ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, database-design

I need some hints on how to develop a inbox, sent, draft functionality for a website. This is so that users can communicate with one another.
i have 3 tables-inbox, sent, draft.
So each table gets populated respectively.

Should I have total 4 tables for this.
Message_Inbox, inbox , draft, sent.
If the user clicks on Inbox or Sent links, the inbox or sent tables with appropriate content taken from Message_Inbox database table should be shown on right. What could be the content taken from message_Inbox table,

I am a beginner in asp.net. So my questions could be naive. I will also do my research

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

This is more to do with database design than asp.net specifically, as the database structure you use could be for a windows forms application, a silverlight app or indeed anything!

My approach to this would be to have *one* table called "Message" which has the following structure:

> MessageId INT NOT NULL IDENTITY
>   FromUserId INT NOT NULL (FK to User Table)
>   ToUserId INT NOT NULL (FK to User Table)
>   IsDraft TINYINT
>   Title NVARCHAR(...)
>   MessageBody NVARCHAR(...)

This way you can store all messages in one table as the only distinction is whether they're a Draft or not, i.e. whether they're yet visible to the intended recipient(`ToUserId`).

So, to retrieve an *Inbox* you'd use SQL similar to

```
SELECT * FROM Message WHERE ToUserId=@UserIdWhoseInboxImRetrieving WHERE IsDraft=0`
```

To retrieve someones draft messages something like

```
SELECT * FROM Message WHERE FromUserId=@UserIdWhoseDraftsImRetrieving WHERE IsDraft=1
```

A users sent items by

```
SELECT * FROM Message WHERE FromUserId=@UserIdWhoseSentItemsImRetrieving WHERE IsDraft=0
```

If you wanted to move to a "multiple recipient" model, you could easily replace the `ToUserId` column with a `Message_Recipient` table that contains one, or more, records containing a `MessageId` and `ToUserId` pair.

Comment: @user575219, glad to have been of help =) If my answer covers the bases for you, please mark it as the "accepted answer" by clicking on the hollow tick at the top of the answer. You might also want to take a minute to review the answers to your other questions and see if there are any you can accept there as well. Accepting answers rewards people who've taken the time to try and help you and also makes it a little more likely that people will try to help you in the future =)